# Getting Error 438 while loading solver both manually as well as through VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, solver, excel-2016, vba

I am trying to load a solver through the following code:

```
Set r = Range("BC3")
For i = 1 To 2

    SolverReset
    score = r.Value

    If score = 1 Then
        SolverLoad loadArea:=r.Offset(1).Resize(8)
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        SolverReset
        SolverLoad loadArea:=r.Offset(1, 1).Resize(11)
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        SolverReset
    Else:
        SolverReset
        SolverLoad loadArea:=r.Offset(1, 2).Resize(12)
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    End If

    Set r = r.Offset(43)

Next i
```

The code gave me an

> error 438: object doesn't support this property or method.

The error is in this line:

```
SolverLoad loadArea:=r.Offset(1, 2).Resize(12)
```

I tried loading the same range manually, It gave me the same error again.

NOTE: I'm loading this same data in a different Excel file successfully! But when I change the file and load the data, it gives me an error.

Kindly help me out if anyone knows the reason for this.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code as it runs fine in 2010.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am wondering as it runs fine on another excel workbook in my same pc! But it won't work in this one. I actually created and ran the code in a separate workbook for testing and then I am now moving it to my original workbook but it wont run.

Comment: Do you have other code in the workbook - especially event code - or any merged cells on the sheet you are referring to?

Comment: Yes there are multiple merged cells. But they were on other sheet as well, but it worked fine there. Also I don't have any event codes in the workbook. Also, when i tried loading the data into the solver manually also, the same error popped up.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I found out that I had Macro-buttons that I kept when I copied the sheet. I deleted them and created them again giving a different name and the problem was solved.